# Asp.Net Core 2.0 error while scaffolding my database to generate Models

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, database-first

I'm getting this error:

## **Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.**

while trying to run this command in Package Manager Console 
Scaffold-DbContext "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;database=frisbee_admin" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -f

Any Idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as follows:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;database=frisbee_admin" -Provider MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -context YourDbContext -Project YourProjectName -Force
```

Comment: @ShehryarKhan, Please post the answer to your question for others to benefit from. I'm having the same issue.